# how to set current location in start of the app?

Tags: android, google-maps, currentlocation

I am working on `GoogleMap`. I get code from the google developer site. I am struggling to set the current location when the application starts.

I successfully implement to `onMyLocationButtonClick()` and when I click, It take me to my current location. But I am implementing something else.
I need to show my current location as the map view start. Any idea?

```
package com.jatinderbhola.mymapapp;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * This demo shows how GMS Location can be used to check for changes to the users location.  The
 * "My Location" button uses GMS Location to set the blue dot representing the users location.
 * Permission for {@link android.Manifest.permission#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION} is requested at run
 * time. If the permission has not been granted, the Activity is finished with an error message.
 */
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
        LocationListener {

    /**
     * Request code for location permission request.
     *
     * @see #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])
     */
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    /**
     * Flag indicating whether a requested permission has been denied after returning in
     * {@link #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])}.
     */
    private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        //
        //setUpMap();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        enableMyLocation();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));

        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // set map type
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        // Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Show the current location in Google Map
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located"));
    }
    /**
     * Enables the My Location layer if the fine location permission has been granted.
     */
    private void enableMyLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission to access the location is missing.
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
            setUpMap();

        } else if (mMap != null) {
            // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked"+mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("HOME"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }

        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
            mPermissionDenied = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        if (mPermissionDenied) {
            // Permission was not granted, display error dialog.
            showMissingPermissionError();
            mPermissionDenied = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays a dialog with error message explaining that the location permission is missing.
     */
    private void showMissingPermissionError() {
        PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
                .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

I try to use setUpMap() but it leads to following error. I am a newbie in android.

```
02-05 15:35:11.303 19034-19034/com.jatinderbhola.mymapapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.jatinderbhola.mymapapp, PID: 19034
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jatinderbhola.mymapapp/com.jatinderbhola.mymapapp.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
at com.jatinderbhola.mymapapp.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:83)
at com.jatinderbhola.mymapapp.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to show your current location on the map?

Comment: yes on the map, as google map shows when we launch the app.

Comment: try [This](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/) or this [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/)  **Note** first google your query and try to find on stackoverflow.

Comment: You may use [Location Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location?hl=en) that includes the current location of the device. You must request permission by adding the relevant Android [location permission](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location?hl=en#location_permissions) to your app if your app needs to access the user's location. You can find examples [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos) that demonstrate the use of location on a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to animate your camera to your position. You can do that by this.Right after you initiate the map.

```
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if(location != null){

        CameraUpdate position = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
        mMap.animateCamera(position);
    }

    CameraUpdate zoom= CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

And this won't work on emulator.If you have an actual phone use this.

```
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

Or Use manual Providers.

```
      locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER OR GPS_PROVIDER
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(getLatitude(), 
getLongitude()), 10.0f), 4000, null);
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
myMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(getLatitude(), getLongitude()))
                .title("My Position").draggable(true));
```

with getLatitude() and getLongitude() are my private methods to retrieve the GPS coordinate, i used the code above on the onCreate of my activity to show me the map with my location as a center point.